# Does Dropbox Auto Camera Upload work with iCloud Photo Library?

Tags: icloud, photos, dropbox

Currently, I store all my photos in iCloud Photo Library. However, I'd like to have another copy of them in Dropbox. Ideally, I'd want my iPad to upload all new images that I add to my iCloud Photo Library on my Mac or iPhone automatically to Dropbox. I have iCloud Photo Library configured to store only thumbnails on the iPad.

**Does the automatic Camera Upload work when I do not download the full-res images to my iPad?**

Comment: What are you asking?  I see three questions:  Can you auto upload from iPad camera to DropBox, can you sync iCloud Photo Library with Dropbox and finally does camera upload work when not downloading the hi-res versions.

Comment: @Allan Basically, I'd like questions two and three answered: can I use auto upload when the iPad downloads only the thumbnails? (Of course, I want Dropbox to upload the original)

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be "No". I tried various things around iCloud Photo Library and Dropbox Camera Uploads.  Here are some results.

- Already since Sierra 10.12.2 (or slightly earlier?), Camera Uploads seems to only work if the iPhone is plugged in in an unlocked state.
- After first enabling iCloud Photo Library, the "camera roll" contains a random selection of photos of different ages (most of them not even shot with the iPhone).
- The program "Image Capture" (comes with MacOS) which can be used to manage the Camera roll shows also these old photos.
- Image capture can not delete any photos from the iPhone anymore, but it can still import these old photos and new photos taken.
- Dropbox camera upload does not seem to do anything anymore after iCloud Photo library has been enabled.  It does not even display the little "Camera icon" right after connection.
- I share pictures with my wife through Dropbox and I do this now by periodically exporting the unmodified originals from Photos on the Mac.